# Does there exist a tar implementation that exits 0 when an error occurs?

Tags: tar, exit-status

[Vim runtime commit 3d37231437fc0f761664a7cabc8f7b927b468767](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/3d37231437fc0f761664a7cabc8f7b927b468767) tries to fix a tar-editing plugin by removing the assumption that a filename doesn't contain the words warning, error, inappropriate or unrecognized. The plugin contained this code to detect errors in case messages were printed but the exit code was 0.

As you can see in the commit,

> The whole if condition seems however slightly dubious.  In case an error
> happened, this would probably already be caught in the previous if
> statement, since this checks for the return code of the tar program.
>
> There may however be tar implementations, that do not set the exit code
> for some kind of error (but print an error message)? But let's keep this
> check for now, not many people have noticed this behaviour until now, so
> it seems to work reasonably well anyhow.

and

```
   " FIXME:is this actually necessary? In case of an error, we should probably
   "       have noticed in the if statement above since tar should have exited
   "       with a non-zero exit code.
```

Hence my titular question: is there a tar implementation that exits 0 even when an error occurs?

I suppose only implementations likely to be used by more than 1 person should count; in particular, I would disqualify examples such as an implementation written as an exercise by students, unless that implementation is an artifact of a published paper and therefore might have real-world use.

Comment: I didn't fully understand why would you need something like that? If you want a tar that exists with zero, either wrap it in a shell function that always returns a 0, or simply ignore the return value. At worst perform a search and replace in `tar` code and replace all `exit()`, `assert()`, and the `main()`function return with 0 then compile from the patched source.

Comment: @td211 the question isn’t asking for one, *i.e.* hoping that one exists or if not, how to implement it; it’s asking *whether* one exists, in the hope that none do (so the code referenced in the question can be removed).

Comment: If such one exists, it is probably badly implemented, since having meaningful exit status is a good practice (or is it a standard practice?). I wouldn't worry about such bad implementations.

Answer (score 0):

As far as you should be concerned, GNU tar and BSD tar have meaningful exit status, which should effectively cover Windows, Linux and Mac OS. I wouldn't worry about bad tar implementations that doesn't report meaningful exit status.